# fscrawler 2.3 with elasticsearch 5.5 getting error string index out of range

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

I have *ElasticSearch* 5.5 with x-pack working without any issue.

But while I trying use *fscrawler 2.3* on a folder I get this error

```
WARN  [f.p.e.c.f.FsCrawlerImpl]
Error while crawling c:/tmp/es: String index out of range: -1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use backslashes in the url of the *_settings.json* - like "`C:\\tmp\\es`"